# Can’t backup to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

So we have an old 6 running 12.4.1 we want to get a backup for so we can restore to a new phone. I’ve tried on a couple machines but I can’t get a clean backup. I get a nondescript “iTunes is unable to backup your phone” error.

What are my options here?  We really just need pics and iMessage restored. Can something like imaging do that?  But the new phone will have 13 on it - can something like imaging work across versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by trying the device to device transfer again - first time didn’t work with some appleID error

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that iTunes is up to date. If using a Mac, then your Mac needs to be updated in order for iTunes to update.

Once its updated then you should be able to backup.

Keep in mind, iCloud can also be used to backup your iPhone as well.

Comment: Beans new iTunes. Too much stuff for iCloud. And iCloud didn’t work either.